# generate a .mobileconfig file when I click a button on web page

Tags: ios, macos, web-clips, mobile-config

I need to generate a .mobileconfig file when I click a button on the web.

Myjob :
there are list of icons on the website , I can select desired icons and click a button , when I click  button I need to generate a .mobileconfig file with selected icons.
I am in a trouble of generating .mobileconfig file. I tried on the web to find an answer but I was unable.
I am so glad if someone is here to help me .What i need to know are

1. What are the requirements I need to have for makinga .mobileconfig (on the web , not through mac)
2. What are the steps of creating a .mobileconfig file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AppConfigurator 2 for create .mobileconfig file and then use it as template on yours web application.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great help Dmytro Hrebeniuk